# Why clearInterval() is not working as it should?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple onclick animation. My onclicked button should move left and then after another click should go back. Something is wrong with the way I put clearInterval(), but I cannot see any mistakes. Can you help me with that?

---

```js
var backBack = document.getElementById('btn');
    var x = 0;
    var loop = 'off';

    function push() {
    if(loop == 'off') {
    var t = setInterval(move,1);
    }
    if(loop == 'on') {
    var t = setInterval(moveBack,1);
    }}

    function move() {
    if(x < 500) {
    x = x + 5;
    backBack.style.left = x + 'px';
    clearInterval(t);
    loop = 'on';
    }}

    function moveBack() {
    if(x > 0) {
    x = x - 5;
    backBack.style.right = x + 'px';
    clearInterval(t);
    }}
```

```css
     #btn {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            background-color: goldenrod;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
        }
```

```html
 <button id="btn" onclick="push()" />
```

Comment: `clearInterval(t);` should throw an error as `t` is undefined outside `push`

Comment: @BrahmaDev but I need it to be there otherwise it will perform without onclick event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put declaration of variable `t` outside the function.
I made some more changet to get your code work.

It should do something like this ?

```js
var backBack = document.getElementById('btn');
var x = 0;
var loop = 'off';
var t;

function push() {
  if (loop == 'off') {
    t = setInterval(move, 1);
  }
  if (loop == 'on') {
    t = setInterval(moveBack, 1);
  }
}

function move() {
  if (x < 500) {
    x = x + 5;
    backBack.style.left = x + 'px';
  } else {
    clearInterval(t);
    loop = 'on';
  }
}

function moveBack() {
  if (x > 0) {
    x = x - 5;
    backBack.style.left = x + 'px';
  } else {
    clearInterval(t);
    loop = 'off';
  }
}
```

```css
#btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="push()" />
```